# Php: Create web push notification

Tags: php, push-notification, web-push

I want to create a web push notification in Php but I don't have the exact procedure for it. Following is the code I found, but it is not working.

```
  <?php
   require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';    
   use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;



    $subscription = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $auth = array(
   'VAPID' => array(
    'subject' => '`enter code here`',
    'publicKey' => '**********',
    'privateKey' => '***********',
   ),
 );

    $webPush = new WebPush($auth);

    $res = $webPush->sendNotification(
    $subscription['endpoint'],
    "Hello!",
     $subscription['key'],
     $subscription['token'],
     true
   );
```

Please suggest the correct steps.

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: may be https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017 it is helpful to you

Comment: Yes there is some internal server error n it does not give notification.

Comment: It's really hard to say what's wrong with just a code snippet - web push can be pretty tough. Have you tried with a service? For example Pushpad has a PHP library: https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-php

Comment: PHP Warning:  require(/home/ambu/web-push-php-example/src/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ambu/web-push-php-example/src/send_push_notification.php on line 2
[Wed Jul 26 16:31:16 2017] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/ambu/web-push-php-example/src/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/abc/web-push-php-example/src/send_push_notification.php.This is the error iam getting in cammand prompt

Comment: The error you have reported (`failed to open stream: No such file or directory`) is not related to web push. It's a problem with PHP and `require`. Make sure that you have that files in the right path.

Comment: Its working now.There was some issue with installation of libraries.

Comment: I want to modify this code.now it gives notification as hello which is already written in code but i want to type some info in textbox and when i submit it i want that info to be displayed in notification.i tried to change it but its not working properly.

Comment: How to replace "Hello" with $text = $_POST['message'];

Comment: fetch('send_push_notification.php', {
              
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
     
                    endpoint:subscription.endpoint,
                    key: key ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('')))) : null,
                    token: token ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('')))) : null,
                }) how can i pass textbox values from above code ?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time my self figuring this out. I'm posting the code as it works for me. Generate the keys from here https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/

```
<?php

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;


// array of notifications
$notifications = array(
 array(
        'endpoint' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/abcd........', // Chrome
        'payload' => 'Hello',
        'userPublicKey' => 'BFHh..........',
        'userAuthToken' => 'DI............',
    )
);

$auth = array(
    'GCM' => 'AAAAKTK8bp4..............', // deprecated and optional, it's here only for compatibility reasons
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'Some Text', // can be a mailto: or your website address
        'publicKey' => 'BGsm2vrV2AMpT.............', // (recommended) uncompressed public key P-256 encoded in Base64-URL
        'privateKey' => 'a89H............', // (recommended) in fact the secret multiplier of the private key encoded in Base64-URL

    ),
);

$defaultOptions = array(
    'TTL' => 300, // defaults to 4 weeks
    'urgency' => 'normal', // protocol defaults to "normal"
    'topic' => 'push', // not defined by default - collapse_key
);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth, $defaultOptions);

$vr = $webPush->sendNotification(
    $notifications[0]['endpoint'],
    $notifications[0]['payload'], // optional (defaults null)
    $notifications[0]['userPublicKey'], // optional (defaults null)
    $notifications[0]['userAuthToken'], // optional (defaults null)
    true // optional (defaults false)
);
```